# wxWidgets wxPanel accessing wxPanelNameStr created in Create function

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxPanel and all I want to access is the wxPanelNameStr created in the Created function. Any help? Is it even possible?

```
(
    wxPanel::wxPanel    (   wxWindow *  parent,
    wxWindowID  id = wxID_ANY,
    const wxPoint &     pos = wxDefaultPosition,
    const wxSize &  size = wxDefaultSize,
    long    style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL,
    const wxString &    name = wxPanelNameStr 
)
```

Currently have a panel linked to a pointer:

```
wxPanel* x = panel->getwxPanel();
```

But is there any way of accessing the base wxPanel and getting the wxPanelNameStr?

```
wxPanel->getName();
```

Comment: `GetName()` doesnt work?

Comment: :D YAY. That works,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
wxPanel* myPanel = new wxPanel(....)
```

then use `myPanel->GetName()`
Note uppercased characters, instead of 'getname()'

Comment: So does that mean that I can do the same for other members of the wxPanel, for example GetId()?

Comment: @Noodlelynx, yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i`m wrong but wxPanel is a type of object(you can`t access an object that are not created), and only objects that are already created are have names.